# how to specify default class name(s) for html controls

Tags: html, css

I am using bootstrap.css(as an external style sheet). Through out my application, Wherever I am using button, I want a couple of css classes `.btn, .btn-primary` to be applied on every button.

One way is to add `class="btn btn-primary"` in every `<button>` declaration in all my application's html files. I found this to be tedious, and inefficient. Tedious because I have to do it for every button declaration, and inefficient because, if I had to apply/remove a class, I ll have to do it for every button declaration.

I am guessing there will be smarter ways to do it. Basically, I would like to know how to set application level default class name(s) to be applied for a given html control.

Comment: I don't know of a pure CSS way to do this, but you could use some simple javascript to add the class on `window.onload`

Comment: If you want to apply `CSS` rules to every element of the same type, you wouldn't need a `class`. I mean, if every `button` will have a class `btn`, why not set the rules to the `button` tag straight away?

Comment: Why not just a CSS selector of 'button', rather than using classes?

Comment: @codebox OP wants to use the styles of an **external stylesheet**. If they had a local copy they could use a preprocessor like LESS and do what you suggest: `button { .btn; .btn-primary; }`.

Answer (score 2):

There is no smarter way, though there are other ways. One would be use javascript or jquery, here is a sample in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $('button').addClass('btn btn-primary')
}
```

But if you ask me, I wouldn't recommend it. Adding the class to html directly is the proper way of doing it.  In future when you or someone else looks at code, you are gonna be confused where the class comes from, unless everything is well documented

Answer (score 0):

As @geekman has suggested, it would not be a good way to add rendering logic into javascript. All the such logic must be a part of the html and the css.

you can find/replace

```
  <button
```

to

```
  <button class='btn btn-primary'
```

from any of the editors you have easily if adding the class to every single button is what you want to do.

Else you can also give css to all button elements by using the 'button' element as the selector in your css file. You will have to check the styling bootstrap is giving the button through firebug and copy that css to the 'button' selector. This might be a better way than JS because the next developer who works on your code and can add a class to any single button and the class would take precedence than your button styling.

Comment: there seems to be three ways to do this                            1. copying all css properties defined for a button in .btn, .btn-primary classes in bootstrap.css;                                  2. Do it via js                                                    3. using LESS/SASS and preprocess styles like `button { .btn; .btn-primary; }`                                                                           *Option (3) seems to be a lot cleaner way of doing this though more non-trivial.*

Comment: Surely sass will be a clean way to do it. But it wont be easy for you to move to sass and extend the .btn or .btn-primary classes from bootstrap. I would suggest you to copy the styling from bootstrap to a button tag in your css. It will far easier to get things running for now.